# GPS not showing current location on map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-maps-v2

I am facing a problem, I am trying to show current location on map. When I use wifi, it works fine, but when I turn the GPS on, it stops showing it, again I turn off GPS it works.. what shall I do, I need to show my location as well as the GPS.

my code is:

```
SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_test);

    // Getting Google Map
    mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location From GPS
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);



    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("STREEEETTT111:  "+db.getIdn(arg0.getTitle()));
            Intent i=new Intent(MapTest.this,PharmacyDetails.class);

            i.putExtra("name", arg0.getTitle());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and I want to attach the screenshots to make my question more clear:

When the GPS is off:

[image: gps off]

And when the GPS is on:

[image]

Please help, thankx

Comment: What happens when you press the location icon in the top right?

Comment: it takes me to my location.. but if u notice, the distances are incorrect, because it is unable to get my current lat and long automatically, which i use to calculate my distance

Comment: Where's your code to calculate the distances?

Comment: Are you shure GPS Position is retrieved? Maybe you are inside and it does not get the fix (try to use one of the thousands of free app in play store to check it).
Maybe that "Best crtieria" is not completely ok for GPS... or it enables GPS lazily.
Try to print out the Lat/Lng you get in your listener. 
If you are in India (sorry, just guessing by names of Pharmacies) you should get something that is nearly: 
Lat 12.95
Lng: 77.69

Comment: @NDorigatti yup I am inside.. Do I need to get out and then try to change my last location?

Comment: @Prakhar yes, the GPS inside does not work most of the time. Use one of the app to check if fix gps has done, or implement your custom "MockLocationProvider" or use one of the mock location apps.

Comment: should try this app to see if you have signal at all: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&hl=en

Comment: I suggest you use the `FusedLocationApi ` to get last known position,it better than `LocationMannager`, you can refer [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android) to get some ideas.

Comment: same problem i'm facing. anybody knows how to solve this ?